How to adjust the uv count
i'm making roblox body. but But there's a limited uv count. I used decimate to reduce the peak and then uv again, then manually merge and split to fix uv and change it to 343 uv count, but it takes too much time and when I put it inside Roblox, the number changed. What do I do if I try to make uv with a set number of uv vertexes at once?

roblox error message The error part is the head. The second sentence

manually adjusted uv

Script to tell uv vertex numbers. uv vertex numbers are in the bottom left.

In order for UV verts to match actual mesh verts you would need to go into edit mode, select an edge with a UV seam, Shift + G (Select Similar) > Seam, then Ctrl+E > Mark Sharp. Then make sure it's set to Shade Smooth in Object mode with the Right mouse context menu. Basically UV edges have to match Edges with split normals AKA Sharp Edges. I don't know if this will fix the problem in Roblox, but I do know how game engines work and that would be my first guess about what that error is trying to communicate.

thank you but it does't work. i think roblox have unique caculation system. and i don't know how caculated blender uv vertex either i think if i can caculate uv vertex my self not use script that may be help really thank you

Maybe it has something to do with overlapping UVs? There are several free UV toolkits that have an Overlapping UVs function, UVToolkit TexTool, you could use those and see if any overlapping UVs come up.

thank you so much i will test it's very helpful
